# Extract german zipcode from line in Java

Tags: java, regex, zipcode

I need to extract the zipcode from file's line.
each line contains an adress and is formatted in a different way.
eg.
"Großen Haag 5c, DE-47559 Kranenburg"
or
"Lange Ruthe 7b, 55294 Bodenheim"

the zipcode is always a five digit number and sometimes follows "DE-".
I use Java.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\b\d{5}\b
```

will match 5 digits if they are "on their own", i.e. surrounded by word boundaries (to ensure we're not matching substrings of a longer sequence of numbers, although those will probably be rare in an address file).

Remember that you'll need to escape the backslashes in a Java string (`"\\b\\d{5}\\b"`).

Comment: thanks! but they are not always "alone". sometimes I have "DE-12345"

Comment: Yes, and this works since the position between the `-` and the number counts as a word boundary. It just won't match a number like `123456` because it contains more than five digits.

Comment: Ah okay, didn't get the maning of word boundaries. Thanks!
Another question concerning Java:
matcher.matches() gives me a boolean but how do I return the zipcode itsself?

Comment: I think you shouldn't rely on the word boundary if the data is entered by users - maybe someone enters D12345. Five digits won't appear anywhere else, so it's a good bet that it's the zip code anyway. That is, unless there are house numbers with five digits, of course, but I'm not aware of any :)

Comment: @tzippy: `matcher.group()` should give you the match result. And of course you can drop the `\b` if you don't need them.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, just found that one out myself.
But there#s a big flaw. A leading zero is recognized as word boundary and then cut off!
But leading zeros are part of the zipcode!

Comment: Oh Sorry, my mistake. Shouldn't convert to int if I want to keep the leading zero =)

Comment: @tzippy For your last mistake, see also http://thedailywtf.com/Comments/Jan48.aspx#188154 "Thank you for invalidating my input before validating it." ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Pattern.matcher("[0-9]{5}")